# To solve the problem of getting factor variable rather than integer after using "row_to_names" in r

Tags: r, format, janitor, r-rownames

series model for predicting yield and putting them into other formulas to generate cash rents forecast.

I want to show the counties' names in the columns and the years in rows in a dataframe.

So I have a vector containing 3 counties' names which all the elements are from other dataframe. I want to put them in all the dataframe and name the columns so I extracted them out. Now I just use an example.

```
ct_name <- c("Adams","Boone","Champaign")
```

And I want to combine then with my predicted yield dataframe table.

```
library(janitor)
table<- matrix(1:6,nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = FALSE)
rownames(table) <- c("2015", "2016")
table <- rbind(ct_name, table)
table <- row_to_names(table, row_number = 1)
table <- data.frame(table)
```

There was integers in matrix. However, after using `row_to_names()`, it all becomes factors or logic.
How can I solve this problem.
I tried `is.numeric() and is.integer()` but it all failed and I need them to be integer to do the calculations!

How should I do? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

Your county names are empty but if you had actual names in them you should do :

```
colnames(table) <- ct_name
```

If you want to change the matrix to dataframe just do

```
table <- data.frame(table)
```

Also `table` is a function in R, so it is better if you name your objects with some different name.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear why you would use `rbind()` to add column names as a row in a table, then use `row_to_names()` to create column names. Once you `rbind()` a character vector to a matrix of integers it will force all data in the matrix to character. Ronak's answer seems like a good solution.

Comment: Yap thx for replying I edit my content now. Basically, it is because my counties' names are from other dataframe. So I want to add it to all the dataframe. Therefore, I extract them and use rbind and row_to_names to name the columns!